# why can't I concatenate these two tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to concatenate two tuples using the overloaded + operator in Python 3.6. I don't have an issue if I include the parenthesis like the first example, but if I leave off the parenthesis as in the second example, I get an error. The message I get is "bad operand type for unary +: 'tuple'". Can anyone explain what is happening?

> newtup = (3,) + (2,4)
>
> newtup = 3, + (2,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unary operator `+` expects valid a operand (int, float etc) on the right side.

In your code `3, + (2, 4)`, you are providing a tuple `(2, 4)` as an operand to `+` which is not a valid operand and so is the error.

In your code:

`newtup = (3,) + (2, 4)`

These are 2 separate tuples `(3,)` and `(2,4)`, so it works.

`newtup = 3, + (2, 4)`

Here its a single tuple with 2 elements `3` and `+(2, 4)` which fails due to above mentioned reason.

Answer (score 4):

It's a precedence issue. `3, + (2, 4)` is parsed as a tuple with elements `3` and `+(2, 4)`, not as adding `3,` and `(2, 4)`. You need the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

It's trying to parse the second line as

`(3, + (2,4))`

Then, it's seeing that you used the unary `+`, as in `a = +5`, with a tuple. This isn't allowed, and thus you get an error. Commas are given very wide precedence (ie they consume as many characters as possible, closer to a + than a *). The reason behind this is that (`biglongexpression1`, `biglongexpression2`) should never mix the two `biglongexpression`s. Everything else is more important and should be evaluated before a comma, and thus `+(2,4)` is evaluated before the comma - because it's a `biglongexpression`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're doing:

```
3, + (2,4)
```

It basically simplifies to two parts `3,` and `+(2,4)`, the second is invalid so you can try new-unpacking in python 3:

```
(3,*(2,4))
```

If on python2 just use second example.

Answer (score -1):

Simple; On the first line you are creating a new tuple made of 2 tuples. 
On the second line you are adding an int to  a tuple. Check this out.

```
 x, y=3, (2,4) # assign  x and y to 3, and (2,4) respectively
 print type(y), type(x)
 <type 'tuple'> <type 'int'>
```

Comment: What is  your aim? what are you trying to do

Comment: I don't understand why it was downvoted. +1 from me.

Comment: The second line *isn't* adding an int to a tuple.

Comment: @PM2Ring you are trying to add to a tuple.

Comment: I'm not trying to add anything. I haven't posted any code on this page. Please see the explanation in user2357112's answer. In the OP's second line, the `+` is the [unary plus](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) operator, it's not the addition operator, which takes two operands.